# What exactly are capture and release?

Tags: logic, intuition, philosophy, paradoxes, nonclassical-logic

### Motivation:

I'm interested in how different people resolve the Liar paradox and other, related phenomena, like the revenge Liar paradoxes, and so on.

I have a copy of *"Formal Theories of Truth,"* by Beall *et al.* and recently I got a digital copy of *"Logic Without Gaps or Gluts"*, by Burgis.  However, I have difficulties getting off the ground with them.

### The Question:

> What exactly are capture and release in (nonclassical) logic?

### The Details:

Simply put, my understanding is that, for each statement $\alpha$, there is some other statement ${\rm Tr}(\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner)$ that means, "$\alpha$ is true" . . . somehow . . . where $\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner$ is the "name" of $\alpha$, which is perhaps the first place my understanding breaks down.

Now:

- **Capture:** $$\alpha \vdash {\rm Tr}(\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner).$$
- **Release:** $${\rm Tr}(\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner)\vdash \alpha.$$

### Thoughts:

My intuition fails to grasp the notion that a statement $\alpha$ can entail "$\alpha$ is true" or *vice versa*.

Maybe this is due to me being used to first order logic. Does that make sense?

I don't know how to articulate this exactly but, from what I remember of a proof of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems (I taught myself), something similar goes on, but with natural numbers and the use of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to describe some $\varphi$ then make $\varphi$ about the number you get; for example:

$$\exists x(Px\to \forall yPy)\tag{$\alpha$}$$

would be something like

$$G:=2^13^25^37^411^213^517^619^723^429^731^8$$

because the symbols map to indices like so:

$$\begin{align}
\exists &\mapsto 1,\\
x&\mapsto 2,\\
( &\mapsto 3,\\
P&\mapsto 4,\\
\to &\mapsto 5,\\
\forall &\mapsto 6,\\
y&\mapsto 7,\\
)&\mapsto 8.
\end{align}$$

Is ${\rm Tr}(\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner)$ (or perhaps $\ulcorner \alpha\urcorner$) like $G$?

That isn't my question; my question is what is highlighted above. This is just me trying to describe my understanding.

---

*NB:* I have included the [intuition](/questions/tagged/intuition) tag because I suppose what I'm getting at is, what is the intuition behind capture and release?

Comment: It sounds like [deflationism]: to assert  that A is true simply amounts to assert A.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is how I resolve the Liar Paradox. I note that, in natural language, a sentence can be one of either (1) a true sentence, (2) a false sentence, or (3) a sentence of indeterminate truth value (e.g. any question or instruction). This is a trichotomy. I also note that "This sentence is false" is said to be a true sentence if and only if it is a false sentence. We can infer from this that it is neither a true sentence nor a false sentence. By elimination, it must for a sentence of indeterminate truth value. This analysis does not require three-value logic.

Comment: ... For details, see https://dcproof.wordpress.com/2023/09/06/this-sentence-is-false/

Comment: But then what about, "This sentence is either false or of indeterminate truth value", @DanChristensen?

Comment: My only concern here is getting a handle on one sentence, namely, "The sentence is false." I make no claims about other sentences.

Comment: Have you seen Burgis ? The author starts from Tarski's T-schema (page 2): $\text {Tr} < α > \leftrightarrow (α)$. Thus (page 3) "Capture and release Rules" are the two sides of the bi-conditional: Capture: $α // \text {Tr}<α>$ and Release: $\text {Tr}<α> // α$.

Comment: If so, the question is: is your question about the intuition regarding [T-sentences: $\text T \ulcorner \phi \urcorner ↔ \phi$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/#TrutTheoDefl)?

Comment: Regarding you example: yes we have a formula $\phi$ and we compute (using encoding rules) the **number** $G$. Then $\ulcorner \phi \urcorner = G$. $\phi$ is a *formula* (a sentence) while $G$ is a term (a name).

Comment: To answer [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4790720/what-exactly-are-capture-and-release#comment10189287_4790720), @MauroALLEGRANZA: yes.

Comment: intuitively speaking, *capture* asserts that the statement "$\alpha$ is true" must be true if the statement $\alpha$ is true, and *release* asserts that the statement $\alpha$ must be true if the statement "$\alpha$ is true" is in fact true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\text T \ulcorner \phi \urcorner$ is a "name" for expression $\phi$; in the classical Gödelian approach to [Arithmetization of Syntax](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan) the name can be produced via encoding.

According to [Deflationsists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/); "there is some strong equivalence between a statement like ‘snow is white’ and a statement like “‘snow is white’ is true,” and this is all that can significantly be said about that application of the notion of truth."

You can compare with JC Beall and David Ripley's [Nonclassical theories of truth](https://entailments.net/papers/nct-9.pdf), **Ch.2 Reasoning with truth** for the "name" of a sentence $A$ and *transparency*: "the principle that $A$ and $\text T \ulcorner A \urcorner$ are intersubstitutable with each other in all non-opaque contexts."

And see page 3: "*Capture* and *release* are argument forms or 'rules of inference'. Capture is the rule going from $A$ to $\text T \ulcorner A \urcorner$, the idea being that the truth predicate 'captures' the content of $A$, and release is the converse, the rule from $\text T \ulcorner A \urcorner$ to $A$."

The theory supporting so-called [Tarski's T-schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/#TrutTheoDefl): "$\text T \ulcorner \phi \urcorner \leftrightarrow \phi$, where $\text T$ is the truth predicate, $\phi$ is a sentence and $\ulcorner \phi \urcorner$ is a name for the sentence $\phi$", is the analysis of "truth talk" in terms of [bi-conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-deflationary/#EquiSche) like: "The proposition that Brutus killed Caesar is true if, and only if, Brutus killed Caesar."

Tarski's formalization of this intuition is reminiscent of so-called [correspondence theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/#CorThe), the theory "that what we believe or say is true if it corresponds to the way things actually are – to the facts."

See also Aristotle's *Metaphysics*, [Book IV, 1011b25](https://www.logicmuseum.com/wiki/Authors/Aristotle/metaphysics/l4): "we define what the true and the false are. To say of what is that it is not, or of what is not that it is, is false, while *to say of what is that it is*, and of what is not that it is not, is *true*."